# USE the Between operator with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for a way to filter two date (year) with the operator between into my sql request but I can't do it. I have difficulties to integrate "Between" into "InnerJoin"
I want to filter on the "Entry_Date" column with "Between" based on the year.

This an example of my table : Patients

| CODE | Name | FirstName | Sex | Date_Of_Birth | SecurityNumber | CountryCode | Entry_date | ReasonCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NALI | DUPONT | F | 09/02/1976 | 3344444448555 | MF | 01/04/2000 | 1 |

This is my SQL Request:

```
SELECT ALL Patients.Code, Patients.Name, Patients.FirstName FROM Patients 
INNER JOIN Pays ON Patients.CountryCode = CountryCode.Code
INNER JOIN Sex ON Patients.Sex = Sex.Code
INNER JOIN ReasonCode ON Patients.ReasonCode = ReasonCode.Code
WHERE Patients.Name LIKE  '".$namePatient."%'
AND Patients.ReasonCode LIKE '".$ReasonCode."%'
AND Patients.CountryCode LIKE '".$CountryCode."%'
ORDER BY Patients.Name ASC
```

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: If you'd do that in the WHERE not the join itself...

Comment: Just add it to the `WHERE` condition: `AND year(Patients.Entry_date) BETWEEN .... AND ....`. Just as you already did with the `LIKE` clauses. It is a local condition, it has nothing to do with the joins.

Comment: Might have to use date stamps in the 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. And cast them to date.  `CAST('1976-02-09' AS DATE)`  It's a format where there's no confusion about which number is the month or day.

Answer (score 1):

if you'd like to filter on year you don't need a BETWEEN; you could use the year function:

```
SELECT ALL Patients.Code, Patients.Name, Patients.FirstName FROM Patients 
INNER JOIN Pays ON Patients.CountryCode = CountryCode.Code
INNER JOIN Sex ON Patients.Sex = Sex.Code
INNER JOIN ReasonCode ON Patients.ReasonCode = ReasonCode.Code
WHERE Patients.Name LIKE  '".$namePatient."%'
AND Patients.ReasonCode LIKE '".$ReasonCode."%'
AND Patients.CountryCode LIKE '".$CountryCode."%'
AND YEAR(entry_date) = {DesiredYear}
ORDER BY Patients.Name ASC
```

> *As pointed out by Pred the comments below using a function in the where clause could result in the query not making use of an index
> depending on your platform*

Comment: using functions on columns in conditions will prevent the server to use indexes, use boundaries instead

Comment: @Pred well, you don't know that, since the OP hasn't specified which platform they're working on.

Comment: I'm working on MYSQL (mariadb) and PHP 7.4

Comment: @cornuz Tell me a platform which can use indexes when the column is used in a function in the condition (not indexed functions/computed columns)

Comment: @Pred I don't need to name a platform to say that your argument makes rather bold assumptions. Even if the most common platforms behave as you say, there could always be an experimental or less known platform that doesn't. More importantly, there are platforms that don't even use indices the way you are used to, most notably column-store engines such as MonetDB.

Comment: @Pred, Mimer SQL will use an entry_date index for YEAR(entry_date) conditions.

Comment: @cornuz This is offtopic here, but I am well familiar with columnstore engines, don't worry. My statement there might be bold, but in general using functions in conditions requires the result to be calculated to do the comparison. In some special cases the engine might be able to do some optimization (like what *jarlh* mentioned), however in general, using functions is in conditions to calculate something what can be described with constants is still considered a bad practice and will still require the evaluation of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Bypassing the discussions around predicates involving expressions instead of column values or literals -

It's in any case good practice to avoid using expressions in filter and join predicate on *any* DBMS. Just as well as I never rely on a DBMS to implicitly cast the string '42' to an integer.

*Liberté, égalité, portabilité* . You might need your SQL code in a new SQL platform, so make sure you're the master and not the victim of what the DBMS does.

So I'd calculate the end of the year of the input date, the beginning of the year of the input date, and use a BETWEEN predicate.

Like so, if you start with `entry_date` . I have already created a helper table with expressions like those, and then range-joined the helper table with the base table, to avoid expression predicates, with success:

```
WHERE search_dt
BETWEEN 
  DATE_ADD(
    LAST_DAY(
      DATE_ADD(entry_date,INTERVAL MONTH(entry_date)*-1 MONTH)
    )
  , INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ) 
AND 
  LAST_DAY(
    DATE_ADD(entry_date,INTERVAL 12-MONTH(entry_date) MONTH)
  )
```